# Force error handling in Golang - or disallow ignoring return values

Tags: go

Say I have a func that returns an error:

```
func conditionalError() error {
   if maybe {
    return errors.New("here")
   }
   return nil
}


err := conditionalError()
```

but if we call it without handling the return value:

```
conditionalError()
```

is there a flag to get the compiler to complain, or maybe just an IDE setting in JetBrains or VSCode to warn about it?

Comment: I think you want https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck

Comment: The compiler does not have a flag to disallow ignored error returned values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an app for that! This type of functionality falls in the category of linters.

https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck